# ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module node_modules/angular-2-local-storage/dist/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3

Tags: angular, angular-local-storage

I am using Angular2 application and getting below error with `npm start` command.
this is whole codes
ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module /home/x/Desktop/koohbaad-web/node_modules/angular-2-local-storage/dist/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in /home/x/Desktop/koohbaad-web/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /home/x/Desktop/koohbaad-web/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /home/x/Desktop/koohbaad-web/src/app/app.module.ts

Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "koohbad-tour",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 192.168.1.193",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^4.*",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.8.0",
    "angular-2-local-storage": "*",
    "angular-star-rating": "^3.0.8",
    "angular2-masonry": "^0.4.0",
    "angular2-recaptcha": "*",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^8.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ng-lazyload-image": "^3.3.3",
    "ng-select": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "ng2-select2": "^1.0.0-beta.10",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^0.5.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "screenfull": "^3.3.1",
    "underscore": "*",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.2.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4",
    "ngx-swiper-wrapper": "4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.42",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ngx-dropzone-wrapper": "^4.0.3",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

And the error I'm getting is

> ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module node_modules/angular-2-local-storage/dist/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3
>   [image]

Please help me out.

Comment: You need to format this properly and explain in more detail how the problem occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your package.json file has an error, there is no version number in angular-2-local-storage. It should be `"angular-2-local-storage": "^2.0.0"`

Please try to remove the node_modules directory afterwards and npm install again.

Answer (score 4):

This is caused because angular-2-local-storage has been built using Angular 5 and it generated metadata files version 4 (which your compiler can't understand because your angular 4 project only can read metadata files up to version 3)
I recommend you update your project to Angular 5 and try again

Answer (score 1):

Angular-2-local-storage error is occurring because in package.json file, this dependency has empty value and the expected version for this dependency is 3. 
So, try installing this dependency again using command **npm install dependencyName**. *(in your case dependency is angular-2-local-storage)*

If no success, then explicitly modify the package.json for angular2-local-storage and give it value 3.0

And about the node-sass error, this is something that we get while making new projects for the first time on a machine. Its a guess as it has happened to me when i had installed angular cli for the first time, and run the application using ng serve. I think its a problem of non-updated modules or cli.

Try to update the node modules, angular-cli and then run the application. 
If problem persists, then goto github page for angular, where i think this issue has been listed.

Answer (score -2):

In case that you can not update your Angular 4 project to Angular 5, for some reason (time), I suggest look this approach for solve this error without migrate. Use repair-mismatch utility for change version on metadata files.

1. In an Angular 4 project install repair-mismatch module as develop dependency

   `npm i @jagcolombat/repair-mismatch --save-dev`
2. Create a file JavaScript, for example rpmm.js, and input the following snippet code:

   `const rpmm = require('repair-mismatch');`
   `rpmm({ modules: ['ngx-vis'] });`

*Note: In this case I use ngx-vis@1.0.1 (compiled with Angular 6) and I want to use this in an Angular 4 project.*

3. Run this command for change metadata version in specified modules (ngx-vis)

   `node rpmm.js`

For more detail read this article:

https://medium.com/@tonytunes2005/solving-error-mismatch-beetwen-angular-versions-b051e7cde418